# Asus pa279q 2560x1440 resolution nvidia hdmi

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

This thread is covered in many posts here, but in the end none of them were useful to solve my issue. As the title says **i d like to reach the full resolution** on my 27inch monitor using an nvidia gforce gt 520m with hdmi output. i was actually able to reach that resolution uninstalling nvidia drivers and using nouveau plus inserting the new mode with xrandr, But, the quality is really bad, **fonts are really blurred**.

I d like to know if this problem is solvable or if people in my situation just gave up and roll back to 1920x1200 resolution. afaiu the card is good enough for that resolution, ubuntu is updated to 14.04. maybe the xrandr settings is wrong? how to properly configure it? is there a way to use nvidia proprietary drivers so i can have opengl?

Comment: after struggling a lot I have a little update. Booting on windows I was able to use the full 2560x1440 resolution. The step was to open the nvidia settings panel and create the custom resolution using the horizontal and vertical frequencies listed in the monitor's manual. Then I had to select "CVT reduce blanking" to get the proper pixel clock (around 240) and that configuration was working great. I am trying on xorg.conf to do the same after gerating the modeline with cvt -r (-r is the option for reduce blanking) but nvidia does not validate that mode and falls back to 1920x1080

Comment: For now the verdict is: HDMI pixel clock is not high enough. HDMI 1 are limited to 165Mhz clock, while this monitor operates at 241.50 with a full resolution. I could force the mode validation in xorg.conf but the monitor ended up with no signal.